# Can a backup of a site be made without Admin tools?

Tags: backup, 2007, administration

A site owner wants to backup their content themselves to feel more confident about their data in the SharePoint site as well as control the frequency of those backups.

Is there a tool that will allow a normal user with no more permission than Full Control on a site to complete a backup of that site's content?  Lists and libraries mostly, but permissions wouldn't hurt.

MOSS 2007 standard edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have limited options for this scenerio.

SharePoint Designer will allow you backup your sites, but you'll run into issues with sites larger than 25MB.  There are work arounds posted on the web, but it's still not a great option for larger sites.

For individual lists / libraries you could create templates and select to keep the content but there are size limitaitons here as well that may give you problems.

Take a look at the Colligo tools, they may provide something that will work for you and they are fairly inexpensive.
http://www.colligo.com/products/sharepoint/

Comment: Looks pretty good.  That would work like MS Groove right?  I like it.

Comment: Actually Groove would be another option, and Colligo is similiar but they offer some different interface options.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to get it done, then it would be possible for you to create a custom process that can run with elevated privileges to complete the job on demand or via a scheduler.

In most environments though that should not be needed if there is adequate Backup and Recovery practices in place that can be successfully demonstrated.

Comment: Does your answer presume access to the server?  I didn't mention it explicitly, but I am looking for a solution that I don't have to beg the admin to pay attention to me.

Comment: Also, do you have an example of such a script, I kinda knew it was possible but I haven't located an example.

Comment: What I am referring to would require writing custom code in Visual Studio and it would be deployed as a feature to the server by the server administrator.  Once the feature has been deployed you would be able to activate it on any site that desires it.  I don't have an example.